# How to refresh my authentication cookie without redirecting to cshtml page in Blazor Server application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

[Screenshot of the Pop-up which appears after inactivity of sometime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KT3B.png)

I am using Blazor Server. The screenshot mentioned above is a razor page. After Inactivity of sometime the app opens the above mentioned pop-up. On clicking `Logout` the app logouts. On clicking the `Stay Login` the pop-up/Modal disappears and should refresh the user cookie ticket.

For refreshing the cookie ticket/Token I am using [SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5H6g.png)

When I use [SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5H6g.png)  on the razor page I get exception saying "response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started."

[Exception Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgttL.png)

To resolve this I made a separate cshtml file and it works fine there. But the problem is that we have to redirect to that cshtml page to refresh user cookie ticket which loses the unsaved data(data in the inputs etc).

[Screenshot of cshtml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4FQp.png)

I am looking for a better solution to refresh user cookie ticket using which I will not lose the unsaved data and the app will continue the same. Waiting for your answers.

Comment: Can you share the code of method RefreshSignInAsync on the razor page?

Comment: It has been resolved. If someone wants to know how then click the following link

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29819

Comment: @TahaAttique, how did you manage to get the Token's values back to the Blazor application in order to make api calls?